# problem with pk fonts with texlive in linux

Tags: fonts, texlive, linux, file-lookup

I have installed TexLive 2012 on a Linux CentOS 5.8 via the user root. The installation has been placed at `/usr/local/texlive/2012`; but for some reason, some pk fonts were placed at `/root/.texlive2012/texmf-var/fonts/pk`.

Now, when I run

```
dvips -Ppk input.tex
```

via the user root, everything is fine. However, when I run the same command from other user accounts (e.g user1) it issues missing fonts error since dvips is not able to find fonts in the directory `/root/.texlive2012/texmf-var/fonts/pk`.

I tried copying the contents of `/root/.texlive2012/texmf-var/fonts/pk` to various places like

```
/home/user1/.texlive2012/texmf-var/fonts/pk
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/pk
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/pk
```

and the I ran `updmap`, `texhash` to update the file name database, but it didn't work.

I tried also to add user1 to the group in the permissions of `/root/.texlive2012/texmf-var/fonts/pk` and its subfolders, but also it didn't work

Do you have any hint how to resolve this?

Note: I am a beginner in linux, so I am sorry if the question was simple.

Comment: With your CentOS, what is the result of the command `kpsepath pk`?

Comment: @PolGab after adding the texlive bin directory to the path, the command you mentioned gives the following output: http://pastebin.com/v60rS62r
,thanks

Comment: I have not been precise enough. What is the result of the command `kpsepath pk` for a non-root user (like `user1` for example)?

Comment: interestingly, the problem has been resolved when I tried today. thanks for you interest and sorry for taking your time

Answer (score 2):

Generated pk files are placed at either `$TEXMFSYSVAR` for system-wide use or at `$TEXMFVAR` for personal use. In your case they are placed at `$TEXMFVAR`. This should not be a problem for other users - they should get the files in their own `$TEXMFVAR`.

Can you post the output of `texconfig conf` from a non-root user somewhere?

PS: Don't work as root, use `sudo`.

Comment: interestingly, the problem has been resolved when I tried today. thanks for you interest and sorry for taking your time

Comment: @M.A: So, can we close your question? @MartinShcröder: how to close this question? Whenever I click `close`, I get the message `Unable to load popup - please try again`...

Comment: @PolGab: I've flagged the moderators.